# Should we remove secondary questions from primary question post?

Tags: discussion

I know you are not supposed to ask two questions in the same question. But what happens when you are editing a question and the OP is asking several questions in the same post?

It feels kinda wrong to make an edit leaving the secondary questions, but it feels wrong to remove them also. So far I've edited the questions leaving the secondary questions untouched and added a comment for the OP to open a separate question for them.

But should I have removed the secondary questions instead?

Comment: If there's a minor *"oh, and while I'm here..."* tacked on the end, I would just remove that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the multiple questions are part of a larger, overarching question, and the post isn't too broad, then go ahead and answer the post on its merits.

If that's not the case, I prefer a close vote as "too broad" and guidance to the OP as to how they can better focus their question.